# Apache Spark, handle nulls in non-nullable columns and string overflow the same as .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_bad_record")

Tags: apache-spark

Schema reconciliation in Spark, I am reading csvs and other text formats into a dataframe with:

```
df = spark.read.schema(schema_with_bad).format(format).option("header", header).option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "_bad_record").load(path)
```

This gives me a nice additional column with the rejected records, but it does not handle nulls in non-nullable columns and I assume not string overflow either (which I guess makes sense since I guess there is no string limit at this point).

To handle the nulls after I have to do another pass on the df, something **similar** to:

```
df = df.withColumn("_bad_record", F.when(F.col(column).isNull(), F.concat_ws(",", *df.columns)  ).otherwise(None))
```

As you can see I am attempting to add the similar concatenated string in the _bad_record for the rows with the nulls
This:

1. I guess is not very efficient.
2. Does not give me the row the way it looks in the file but in the resulting dataframe.

Is there a way to "enhance" how that first read/pass on the file is done to make it also do the additional checks I want?

How are you usually solving this?